# Does knowing half of $A$ bits makes it east factoring $N=AB$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

When trying to factor $N$, where $N=AB$, and $A,B$ are big prime numbers.

Does knowing the first $k$ bits of $A$ can make it easy factoring $N$? For example, knowing half of $A$ bits.

Comment: just knowing the number of bytes of $A$ is a big hint

Comment: What do you mean by "easy"?

Comment: @Rob easier then factoring A with the size of the unknown bits.